Meaning of "but it is all of a piece" in "The Murder on the Links"
I'm reading The Murder on the Links by Agatha Christie. In chapter 21, "Hercule Poirot on the case", Poirot explains why Giraud has bad luck with the hair he found in the dagger. He says:

"But it is all of a piece. Always facts must be twisted to fit the theory."

What does "But it is all of a piece" mean? I assume he means
a small piece of the puzzle, but I'm not sure.

"Of a piece" is an idiom meaning "the same kind of thing." Collins Dictionary has the following definitions:

in British English: of the same kind; alike
in American English: of the same sort; alike; consistent (with).

Poirot is saying that it was bad luck for Giraud that even though Madame Renaud's hair is almost completely grey, the particular hair of hers around the dagger was black. He adds, however, that bad luck alone is not what led Giraud to assume that the hair was Jack's rather than his mother's. He says that this assumption is of a piece with, i.e., consistent with, Giraud's usual pattern of behavior: Giraud always twists facts to fit his preconceived theory, rather than developing a theory to fit the facts.
